# Git push Failed to connect to gitlab.com port 443: Bad access

Tags: git

I use git with gitlab.

I'm no longer able to push to my repo from windows pc. git is no longer asking for password.

The error:

```
achita@DESKTOP-IAEDBE2 MINGW64 /c/RachitaData/Git/Projects/Pms (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Rachita@DESKTOP-IAEDBE2 MINGW64 /c/RachitaData/Git/Projects/Pms (master)
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/aarfid/aarfidProjects.git/': Failedto connect to gitlab.com port 443: Bad access
```

**EDIT**

Ping command cannot find host

```
 ping https://gitlab.com/aarfid/aarfidProjects.git
    Ping request could not find host https://gitlab.com/aarfid/aarfidProjects.git. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\Rachita\Downloads\curl-7.33.0-win64-ssl-sspi>ping gitlab.com

Pinging gitlab.com [104.210.2.228] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 104.210.2.228:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
Control-C
^C
```

**Curl**

```
    C:\Users\Rachita\Downloads\curl-7.33.0-win64-ssl-sspi>curl https://gitlab.com/aarfid/aarfidProjects.git
    curl: (7) Failed connect to gitlab.com:443; No error

C:\Users\Rachita\Downloads\curl-7.33.0-win64-ssl-sspi>curl gitlab.com
curl: (7) Failed connect to gitlab.com:80; No error
```

Although I'm able to open gitlab.com on the browser

**EDIT1**

**firewall settings**

```
C:\Users\Rachita\Downloads\curl-7.33.0-win64-ssl-sspi>netsh advfirewall show currentprofile

Private Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON
Firewall Policy                       BlockInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Disable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Disable
LogDroppedConnections                 Disable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096
```

**SOLUTION**

I turned off the firewall and the problem was solved as suggested by das_j in comment

**To turn wirewall off**

```
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
```

Comment: Has your configuration either locally or remotely changed recently to your knowledge?

Comment: no . I just started using git got gitlab 2 days ago. It was working fine a day ago.

Comment: Please copy the text from your terminal instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Can you connect via HTTPS to gitlab.com using e.g. wget or curl? Likely a network access restrictions and/or denial of service.

Comment: You can't ping on a port/protocol. For ping, use `ping gitlab.com` and for HTTP test use `curl https://gitlab.com/aarfid/aarfidProjects.git`

Comment: @user3159253 not able to connect using curl

Comment: ping can often be prevented by a firewall. Is there a company firewall between you and the internet? Do you need to use a proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turned off the firewall and the problem was solved as suggested by das_j in comment

To turn wirewall off

```
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
```

Comment: You have very impressive solution! totally disable firewall to just be able to push to git and expose your computer to network. I guess firewall was there for a reason.

Comment: @AaA was that sarcasm? Confusing for the newbies.

Comment: @carloswm85, yes it was! You should be adding git port and IP to firewall instead of totally disabling it unless you are looking for a new home for some ransomware and computer viruses!

Comment: @AaA ok, good to know. Thanks for the clarification. I need to read more about how firewalls work.

Answer (score 2):

There was days that you only needed to protect your PC from incoming connections, nowadays there is almost no threat from incoming connection, there is only outgoing that you have to block.

I have Firewall blocked all outgoing connections by default, unfortunately windows firewall log is completely useless (never writes anything at least for my windows 10, in few machines) I had to install another firewall and disable windows firewall to see what program actually trying to connect out during push.

Here are 3 that I needed to allow access

port 53 and 443 for git-credential-manager-core.exe

- selected during install otherwise git-credential-manager.exe)

port 53 and 443 for git-remote-https.exe

- If you are using https git repo url otherwise git-remote.exe or any of the others depending on your protocol, there are a few of them.

port 443 and 53 for TortoiseGitProc.exe

- Since I am using TortoiseGit too, if you are using command line or different GUI (e.g. source tree) try finding the process for that.

**Note:** all these exe files are in `Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\` folder

Comment: Let's say I'm behind a proxy, how should I apply this solution?

Comment: is your proxy behind the firewall or inside? you can ask the person who setup the proxy to open the firewall for you, but I don't think they have put proxy and then block it with firewall. As for git to connect through proxy there is a small config help in here 

https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765

Also the above solution only applies if your git is blocked by firewall, specifically windows firewall.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Vpn**
Enable local network in your **Vpn client** settings and make sure you can telnet to the 443 port on the URL. double check if you want to connect to github or gitlab.