# Error When Clone/Push Git Repos 443: Bad access, but no proxy used

Tags: git, github, push, clone

I am having really strange issue when do these operations clone/push with git remote repo.

Let's say I'm trying to push my changes to remote repo.

```
git push origin master
```

Then I will get this error.

**fatal: unable to access '[Remote_Repo]': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Bad access**

I checked this issue and everyone saying this related to proxy. But I am quiet sure that I am not using a proxy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here what happened. Kaspersky internet security blocked the connection to the git server and that's why I got that error.

**So anyone  facing the similer kind of issue, try disabling your anti virus first.**

Comment: Yes, that was part of the "host of reasons" I mentioned before: I have included the AV one in the answer for more visibility, as well as a more sensible recommendation (than disabling the AV)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the nature of the remote server (here github.com)

That could simply means an issue on the remote server side (even though there is [no recent alert](https://status.github.com/messages)).
Locally, it could be a [firewall issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34945906/6309) or an [host of other causes](http://techzap.net/to-connect/unable-to-connect-to-port-443.html) (make sure your Windows is up-to-date with the latest patches

As the [OP Rukshan Dangalla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049442/rukshan-dangalla) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600793/error-when-clone-push-git-repos-443-bad-access-but-no-proxy-used/44600808?noredirect=1#comment76230949_44600808), the anti-virus (Kaspersky internet security) was blocking 443.
You can see an example of such an interference in [this issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/601), where it seems like the antivirus interferes with connection attempts, leading git to think connections were unsuccessful.
**Adding git to a whitelist in the AV can be a good workaround**.
(Do *not* disable the AV!)

---

Also check from the command-line if you have a credential helper (which might have cached the wrong credentials)

```
git config -l|grep credential
```

See "[How to sign out in Git Bash console in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)": That is **[Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)** using the latest [Microsoft Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows).

From [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37673695#37673695):

> I tried the cloning in another machine which connected to same network and it worked. Issue is in my machine :(

---

As a last resort, You can also try and use an ssh url (if you have registered a public key on the server side)

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<username>/<reponame>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I tried turning off the firewall as well. But no luck. Also I tried the same thing in another computer. Everything worked fine including push and etc. Now I'm suspecting this issue related to windows updates :/

Comment: Other thing I wanted to tell, when I trying to connect to the remote repo using the VisualStudio, it is working (in the machine that I can't do this in command line). That's very strange.

Comment: @RukshanDangalla From the command line, do you have a credential helper? (I have edited the answer). If yes, and if its value is manager, open you "Maange Windows Credential", and look for a github.com entry.

Comment: yes I have the credential helper and there is a entry for Github in the manager. Shall I remove it?

Comment: @RukshanDangalla Yes, then push again: a popup will ask you for your GitHub credentials: enter them again. It should work.

Comment: yes I removed it and then tried to push. No window appeared asking credentials and gave me the same error I mentioned in the question :(

Comment: Yes I am trying that out. But here, I tried to push using Visual Studio while credentials removed. Now I can see a window pop up to get credentials. So this issue totally related to command line

Comment: Yes SSH worked :). It's really strange. Thanks for the support. Any idea why this happened?

Comment: @RukshanDangalla Can you try and remove any credential line from your git config files (do a `git config -l --show-origin`)? Then try to push (after restoring the http url with `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>`): would a push from command-line prompt you for a username/password?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146925/discussion-between-rukshan-dangalla-and-vonc).

Comment: finally I found the culprit, it's my anti virus. Somehow it's blocking the connection.
Thank you very much for the help sir. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the TripMode application, since I was allowing specific apps to use the internet bandwidth, so Git and it's related threads could not access to internet.

Solution: Stop TripMode or allow Git and it's related threads.