# Git push failed: 403

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, push

Today I tried to setup a project with my friend. First, we decided to use GitLab, but later, we switched to GitHub. At the beginning, everything worked fine, I was able to push, pull and so on. But later, maybe 45-60 minutes, every push requests failed. Pull works fine.

I really don't know what to do, heres the error: [IntelliJ IDEA Git Push fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzxNQ.png)

We are working together using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5 and also tried switching to SSH - which did not help.

Do you guys know how to fix this error? The repository still exists and I still have access to it. I also tried re-creating the project (from GitHub) and I also tried re-installing Git.

Comment: I'm guessing your remote is incorrect. What happens when you try to clone the repo from github? i.e. in the terminal, navigate to a new directory and run: `git clone https://github.com/your-username/your-repo.git`?

Comment: It'll create a new project but the error still exists then.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that you are the owner of that repo, and that you don't have [2FA (two factyor authentication) activated](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/) (if you have 2FA, see "[IntelliJ How to access GIT remote repositories with 2-factor authentication](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206537004-How-to-access-GIT-remote-repositories-with-2-factor-authentication)")

Double-check also how your GitHub account is [registered in IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/registering-github-account-in-intellij-idea.html).

Comment: @mickedplay can you reproduce the issue when pushing (using your GitHub account) from another machine?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine on my other device. I'll try to re-install my IntelliJ-IDEA. If it's not working, I'll write back here. If it does, I'll do the same.

Comment: Okay, it's not working. Re-installed IntelliJ IDEA did not change anything. Using another device works fine. Any more ideas?

Comment: @mickedplay double-check your path (try with a simplified path, especially if you are on Windows). See also if you have a credential manager activated (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600808/6309).

Comment: Doubled checked path, no credential manager and it's still 403.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Git` -> `Manage Remotes` in IntelliJ. If you're using **https** instead of **ssh** you should specify your url with username: `https://YourUsername@github.com/your_account_name/your_repository.git`

Also check your InelliJ settings `Ctrl+Alt+S` and search for `GitHub`. Then **add** or **fix** your account.

You may also want to [generate an access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new) which can be revoked, also if using two-factor-authentication.

Then push or do some operation that needs e.g. write privileges.